# Is there any Rest client that can send a GET Http request with message body apart from cURL ? (Firefox,Google REST client does not work)

Tags: rest, http, httpclient

I have a special requirement where I have to pass in a complex JSON structure (lists of Jobjects) to query the backend data. Each Jobject is picked up and the condition string is formed to search the database, the results aggregated and sent back as a single server response.

While GET+Message body works - tested it using cURL, I am loking for a more user friendly client for testing and validation.

Comment: Have you tried [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Comment: Is this a command line thing, or are you building this into a system? You could write something in node.js, python, perl, pretty much any scripting language.

Comment: if you want to do it in the browser, have a look at postman, in Chrome apps. We use that for testing APIs we build.

Comment: Neither Fiddler nor Postman allows ingesting a request body in GET

Comment: I am building a webservice and the user expects to test using friendly clients like Firefox and likes

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from RFC 7231, section 4.3.1:

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
>     sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
>     implementations to reject the request.

And sections 3.3 of RFC 7230 defines:

> The presence of a message body in a request is signaled by a
>     Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field.  Request message
>     framing is independent of method semantics, even if the method does
>     not define any use for a message body.

So yes, a GET request may have a message body. But as long as you don't have absolute control of all clients, servers and systems in between I would recomend against using this. To easily there might be a system (maybe a proxy) not accepting these requests.

And if you have access to all systems: why not sending it using a different HTTP verb?

Comment: I can always do this using POST but was wanting to avoid it since am just querying the back end data. There is no change to the resource collection for this API - only retrieval.